# How to add a new field to underlying view?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I need to add an existing field to a production SQL Server view (the field in the table exists, just need to include it in the view). Will this cause any problems with the current Entity Framework the web solution is using in production (already created from the view) or will it continue to function normally?

Comment: Should be fine but test it locally on your dev machine and find out (should be easy to replicate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per another source "EF will ignore it when querying and updating. However if it’s a non-nullable db column, inserts and updates will fail."